# What is the proper/idiomatic way to filter or map based on surrounding context in functional programming?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

In functional programming, filtering based on the characteristics of a single item is relatively straightforward -- e.g., filtering to find only odd numbers:

```
const arrayOfInfo = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,11,13,15,16,17,19]

const onlyOddNumbers = arrayOfInfo.filter(function(item) {

  return (item % 2 == 1) ? true : false

})
```

However, I'm not sure what the idiomatic way of doing things is if I need context -- in other words, knowing something about the surrounding items.  For example, if I wanted to filter for only the items that were surrounded by odd numbers on either side, I could do this (I'm taking advantage of some JavaScript characteristics and not even bothering to check whether the indexes exist first):

```
const surroundedByOneOddNumber = arrayOfInfo.filter(function(item,index) {

  const itemBefore = arrayOfInfo[index - 1]
  const itemAfter = arrayOfInfo[index + 1]
  return ((itemBefore % 2 == 1) && (itemAfter % 2 == 1)) ? true : false

})
```

This becomes more obvious as a problematic or inefficient way to write code if I wanted to find numbers surrounded by two odd numbers on each side:

```
const surroundedByTwoOddNumbers = arrayOfInfo.filter(function(item,index) {

  const itemBefore = arrayOfInfo[index - 1]
  const itemTwoBefore = arrayOfInfo[index - 2]
  const itemAfter = arrayOfInfo[index + 1]
  const itemTwoAfter = arrayOfInfo[index + 2]
  return ((itemBefore % 2 == 1) && (itemTwoBefore % 2 == 1) && (itemAfter % 2 == 1) && (itemTwoAfter % 2 == 1)) ? true : false

})
```

Obviously, if I wanted to do something like find only numbers surrounded by 50 odd numbers on each side, this would be completely pointless to write code like this.

Is there a good way to address this with functional programming, or is this a case where it is better to drop down to for/while loop-style?

CodePen to play with the samples: https://codepen.io/jnpdx/pen/MvradM

Comment: My first intuition is to create a loop, perhaps recursion would be an attractive solution.

Comment: You wouldn't write out all these conditions. You'd just `slice` the array and test the condition on `every` element of that slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea of functional programming is to write pure functions without side-effects

`Array.filter` is functional because it returns a new array, without mutating the original one. You can run that method on the same array millions of times without changing it.

If your logic gets complex, the code gets complex too, there is no functional magic which solves your domain problems.

However, you could make a `createFilter` function, which would create your filter function based on your domain requirements like:

```
const createFilter = ({
  before = e => true,
  after = e => true
}) => (entry, idx, entries) =>
```

before(entries[idx - 1]) && after(entries[idx + 1])
      }; 
    }

```
// This will return [ 4, 4 ] I guess ;)
[1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 4, 7].filter(createFilter({
   before: (e) => e % 2 === 0,
   after: (e) => e % 2 === 1,
}))
```

The same way you could get only values where the item before is 50 and after 100:

```
[50, 1, 100, 4, 50, 3, 100].filter(createFilter({
  before: (e) => e === 50,
  after: (e) => e === 100
})) // pretty sure the output is [1, 3]
```

So this way you have a reusable `filterCreator`, extend it to your needs ;)

## Update

@Aadit M Shah yes, after reading the OP again, I came to the conclusion, that my method would still work, you just have to write your own `filterCreator` function. And there is nothing wrong with the `Array.filter` actually.

```
const filterBySurrounding = (n, meetCondition) => {
  return (item, idx, array) => {
    return n <= idx && idx + n <= array.length - 1
      ? array.slice(idx - n, idx).every(meetCondition) &&
        array.slice(idx + 1, idx + 1 + n).every(meetCondition)
      : false

  }
}

const isOdd = n => n % 2 === 1
array.filter(filterBySurrounding(50, isOdd))
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. This is not what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I've created another example, which solves the problem.

Comment: There's a mistake in your `filterBySurrounding` function. It should be `idx + n <= array.length - 1`. You forgot the `- 1` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a closure over the count of the left and right needed odd values, then take the left and right values and check every element and return the result of the check for filtering.

A special case is the count of zero, there you need to check just the actual element.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19],
    odd = item => item % 2,
    getOdds = count => (a, i, aa) => {
        var temp = aa.slice(i - count, i).concat(aa.slice(i + 1, i + 1 + count));
        return count
            ? temp.length === 2 * count && temp.every(odd)
            : odd(a);
    };

console.log(array.filter(getOdds(0)));
console.log(array.filter(getOdds(1)));
console.log(array.filter(getOdds(2)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A smarter approach is to count contiguous odd parts and use the array for filtering.

> Check if `16` is surrounded by two odd numbers
>
> ```
> name   values                                                     comment
> -----  ---------------------------------------------------------  --------------------
> array  [  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19]
> left   [  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  0,  1,  2]
> right  [  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  3,  2,  1,  0,  2,  1]
>                                                      16           item to check
>                                                   3               left count >= 2
>                                                           2       right count >= 2
>                                                     true          result for filtering
> ```

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19],
    odd = item => item % 2,
    left = array.reduce((r, a, i) => (r[i] = odd(a) ? (r[i - 1] || 0) + 1 : 0, r), []),
    right = array.reduceRight((r, a, i) => (r[i] = odd(a) ? (r[i + 1] || 0) + 1 : 0, r), []),
    getOdds = count => (a, i) => count
        ? left[i - 1] >= count && right[i + 1] >= count
        : odd(a);

console.log(array.filter(getOdds(0)));
console.log(array.filter(getOdds(1)));
console.log(array.filter(getOdds(2)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `count == 0` is not a special case. `every` can handle that fine.

Comment: @bergi, i don't understand, please explain.

Comment: Just write `return temp.every(odd)`? And I don't see why we should check the element itself when there are no surroundings.

Comment: Btw, I think we need to make sure that `i - count` doesn't get negative in the `slice`

Comment: no. it does not work this way, without checking the length and other sanity checks.

Comment: TBH, I don't understand what the `temp.length == 2 * count` check is doing. (But maybe I'm just overlooking the requirements from the OP)

Comment: the count of elements who are odd must be the same as the length of left and right array.

Comment: Ah, of course - that's the same behaviour the OP had when checking `undefined` for oddity; he wants to ignore those that are not surrounded by any numbers completely. Basically the difference between "*it is surrounded by odd numbers*" and "*all numbers that surround it are odd*".

Comment: Nice answer. However, I feel that your smarter approach is less readable and more confusing than the normal approach. It might be faster but is it really worth it? After all, premature optimization is the root of all evil. Nevertheless, you deserve an upvote. =)

Comment: Just a suggestion, why don't you use `console.log(JSON.stringify(array))` next time? The array fits in one line. Hence, you don't have to scroll to see all the output. Furthermore, you don't need to add distracting CSS to your code snippets. Just an aesthetic difference but it'll make your answer better.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd do:

```js
const zipperFilter = (p, xs) => {
    const before = [];      // elements before x
    const after  = [...xs]; // x followed by elements after x, shallow copy
    const result = [];

    while (after.length > 0) {
        const x = after.shift(); // remove x; thus, after = elements after x
        if (p(before, x, after)) result.push(x);
        before.unshift(x); // before = x followed by elements before x
    }

    return result;
};

const isOdd = n => n % 2 === 1;

const surroundedByPossiblyNOddNumbers = n => (before, x, after) =>
    before.slice(0, n).every(isOdd) &&
    after.slice(0, n).every(isOdd);

const surroundedByStrictlyNOddNumbers = n => (before, x, after) =>
    before.length >= n &&
    after.length >= n &&
    before.slice(0, n).every(isOdd) &&
    after.slice(0, n).every(isOdd);

const xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,11,13,15,16,17,19];

const ys = zipperFilter(surroundedByPossiblyNOddNumbers(1), xs);
const zs = zipperFilter(surroundedByPossiblyNOddNumbers(2), xs);
const as = zipperFilter(surroundedByStrictlyNOddNumbers(1), xs);
const bs = zipperFilter(surroundedByStrictlyNOddNumbers(2), xs);

console.log(JSON.stringify(ys));
console.log(JSON.stringify(zs));
console.log(JSON.stringify(as));
console.log(JSON.stringify(bs));
```

What is a `zipperFilter`? It's a context sensitive list filter function based on the [zipper data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure)) for lists. Any time you want to do context sensitive data processing (e.g. image processing) think of zippers.

The advantages of creating a custom `zipperFilter` function are:

1. It's more efficient than using the native `filter` method. This is because we don't have to keep using `slice` to generate the `before` and `after` arrays. We keep a running copy of both and update them on every iteration.
2. The `before` array is maintained in the reverse order. Hence, lower indices always correspond to closer neighbors. This allows us to simply `slice` the number of closest neighbors we want.
3. It's readable, generic and informs the reader that the filtering is context sensitive.

Hope that helps.